# How to get the Application Name displayed in Task Manager (Powershell)?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to get a list of the "Process > Apps > Name" displayed in Task Manager. These specific strings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBAE0.png

I've tried the following but none have the information I need.

```
Get-Process | Select *
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Select *
tasklist /v
```

Comment: I can't readily find a reference to it but if I recall correctly, the Applications tab from taskmanager shows the top level windows of a process. You can't get that information easily from the commandline.

Comment: Ah, found one. [Window Title:](https://books.google.be/books?id=0KZCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT110&lpg=PT110&dq=taskmanager+shows+top+level+windows+title&source=bl&ots=lLsguDly4_&sig=Ibn_DYeJ_xeNE3wBTwC1gn6rJT4&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWiuba-OrOAhXQ0RoKHRx3AUcQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=taskmanager%20shows%20top%20level%20windows%20title&f=false) *"If the process owns any visible windows, shows the text of the title bar of a top-level window, similar to the Applications tab of Task Manager."*

Answer (score 2):

Once you know what to look for, it all seems trival but the key information is that [Task Manager shows the text of the title bar](https://books.google.be/books?id=0KZCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT110&lpg=PT110&dq=taskmanager+shows+top+level+windows+title&source=bl&ots=lLsguDly4_&sig=Ibn_DYeJ_xeNE3wBTwC1gn6rJT4&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWiuba-OrOAhXQ0RoKHRx3AUcQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=taskmanager%20shows%20top%20level%20windows%20title&f=false) of a top level window.

Getting a list then of processes containing a Top Level window can be done as this example in [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/05/22/get-windowtitle-ps1/) shows

```
Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle –AutoSize
```

Comment: I'm looking for the exact value displayed in the Applications tab of the Task Manager. In the example image I posted above, the value of MainWindowTitle is "TeamViewer". I'm looking specifically for "TeamViewer 11 (32 bit)".

Comment: mmm, it seams that `Get-Process | where {$_.description} | select description` is a better match for what you are after but determining if a process is 32 or 64 bit is more difficult than expected. The closes I got is by reading the exe file using [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/889267/6825) as a template but I don't have the stamina right now to filter out the hex values. If you want, this is where I stopped `(gc C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe -Raw) -match '\x50\x45\x00\x00\x64'`

Comment: I don't think the output of Get-Process is related to the value Task Manager displays. I dug around for a more concrete example:

Microsoft Network Realtime Inspection Service and NisSrv.exe
http://imgur.com/a/CdvGR

Comment: I'm stumped. I've tried to get the information as `administrator` and as `system` using `gps` en `gwmi` but both fail to get me the executable path or description for `NisSrv`.

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
Get-Process | Select-Object company
```

what you are looking for? Or something like

```
tasklist /APPS
```

Comment: In the example I posted above, I'm looking specifically for "TeamViewer 11 (32bit)". This is not the same value as the company or the window title.